# Adjusting the bounds of a QQ plot in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R programming and I just want to know how to change the bounds of a QQ plot. Doing qqnorm(x) automatically adjusts the bounds to fit the data set however I wish to change them slightly and to end on integers rather than arbitrary places. So if I wanted to make a QQ plot of x, and I wanted to have the bounds to be -5 and 5 for the x min and max and -10 and 10 for the y min and max, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually possible to modify the range of the axis scales on a plot by specifying **xlim**
or **ylim** arguments. Fo example:

```
  x <- rt(200, df = 5)
  qqnorm(y,xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-10,10))
```